# How to click capture an image WITHOUT Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, family-tree, gedcom

I am using a website called https://www.familyecho.com/ it has an API to create these family trees. https://familyecho.com/?page=api this is the API website that has information about the API. Now that I have generated a family tree I want to download an image of it or somehow save it to my computer. But, I do not want use Selenium because it opens up new tabs.

the GEDCOM script:

```
GED = """0 HEAD
1 GEDC
2 VERS 5.5.5
2 FORM LINEAGE-LINKED
3 VERS 5.5.5
1 CHAR UTF-8
1 SOUR GS
2 NAME GEDCOM Specification
2 VERS 5.5.5
2 CORP gedcom.org
3 ADDR
4 CITY LEIDEN
3 WWW www.gedcom.org
1 DATE 2 Oct 2019
2 TIME 0:00:00
1 FILE 555Sample.ged
1 LANG English
1 SUBM @U1@
0 @U1@ SUBM
1 NAME Reldon Poulson
1 ADDR 
2 ADR1 1900 43rd Street West
2 CITY Billings
2 STAE Montana
2 POST 68051
2 CTRY United States of America
1 PHON +1 (406) 555-1232
0 @I1@ INDI
1 NAME Robert Eugene /Williams/
2 SURN Williams
2 GIVN Robert Eugene
1 SEX M
1 BIRT
2 DATE 2 Oct 1822
2 PLAC Weston, Madison, Connecticut, United States of America
2 SOUR @S1@
3 PAGE Sec. 2, p. 45
1 DEAT
2 DATE 14 Apr 1905
2 PLAC Stamford, Fairfield, Connecticut, United States of America
1 BURI
2 PLAC Spring Hill Cemetery, Stamford, Fairfield, Connecticut, United States of America
1 FAMS @F1@
1 FAMS @F2@
1 RESI 
2 DATE from 1900 to 1905
0 @I2@ INDI
1 NAME Mary Ann /Wilson/
2 SURN Wilson
2 GIVN Mary Ann
1 SEX F
1 BIRT
2 DATE BEF 1828
2 PLAC Connecticut, United States of America
1 FAMS @F1@
0 @I3@ INDI
1 NAME Joe /Williams/
2 SURN Williams
2 GIVN Joe
1 SEX M
1 BIRT
2 DATE 11 Jun 1861
2 PLAC Idaho Falls, Bonneville, Idaho, United States of America
1 FAMC @F1@
1 FAMC @F2@
2 PEDI adopted
1 ADOP 
2 DATE 16 Mar 1864
0 @F1@ FAM
1 HUSB @I1@
1 WIFE @I2@
1 CHIL @I3@
1 MARR
2 DATE Dec 1859
2 PLAC Rapid City, Pennington, South Dakota, United States of America
0 @F2@ FAM
1 HUSB @I1@
1 CHIL @I3@
0 @S1@ SOUR
1 DATA
2 EVEN BIRT, DEAT, MARR
3 DATE FROM Jan 1820 TO DEC 1825
3 PLAC Madison, Connecticut, United States of America
2 AGNC Madison County Court
1 TITL Madison County Birth, Death, and Marriage Records
1 ABBR Madison BMD Records
1 REPO @R1@
2 CALN 13B-1234.01
0 @R1@ REPO
1 NAME Family History Library
1 ADDR
2 ADR1 35 N West Temple Street
2 CITY Salt Lake City
2 STAE Utah
2 POST 84150
2 CTRY United States of America
0 TRLR

"""
```

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
}
response = requests.post('http://api.familyecho.com/', headers=headers, data={'format':'json','operation':'temp_view','family': GED})
response = response.json()
tree_id = response["url"].split("i=")[-1]
print(response["URL"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
response = requests.post('http://api.familyecho.com/',
                                 headers=headers,
                                 data={'format': 'json',
                                       'operation': 'temp_view',
                                       'family': GED,
                                       "hide_header": 1,
                                       "hide_sidebar": 1,
                                       "hide_navbar": 1,
                                       "zoom_factor": 2,
                                       }).json()
        URL = 'https://api.microlink.io'
        params = {'url': response['url'], 'screenshot': 'True'}
        response = requests.get(URL, params)
        return response.json()['data']['screenshot']["url"]
```

an API that takes screen shots.